# Read PLC from web

Tags: plc

```
public class Http_Read_PLC_Value {
public static void main(String args[]){
    String nextLine;
    URL url = null;
    URLConnection urlConn = nullone
    InputStreamReader  inStream = null;
    BufferedReader buff = null;
    try{
        url = new URL("http://api.enda.com/devive/mac_address/password/read/MW/0");
        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        inStream = new InputStreamReader( urlConn.getInputStream());
        buff= new BufferedReader(inStream);
        while (true){
            nextLine =buff.readLine();  
            if (nextLine !=null){
               System.out.println(nextLine);      
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException e) { System.out.println("Check URL :" + e.toString() ); }
    catch(IOException  e1) { System.out.println("Can't read : "+ e1.toString() ); }
  }
}
```

OUTPUT of Console :  `{"Result":[1572],"Status":"OK"}`

### My Question :

The value of bracked is changing between 0 & 28800 and boolean. That value  sometimes one character (like[2]), sometimes five character (like[27924]), sometime [true] or [false].When I run that prg, I need a string value of bracked. How I can get ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using middleware processing, I recommend the next open source middleware project.

http://www.lecpserver.com:3001/#/node_read_write

https://github.com/xeden3/LECPServer

LECPServer allows users to read and write data of multiple PLCs through Ajax, etc., and the method is very simple, and you can modify it to the mode you want according to your needs.

```
// send
{
    "action": "plc_read_nodes",
    "node": [
        "NODES.MODBUS.C0000",
        "NODES.MODBUS.H0000"
    ]
}

// response
{
    "errcode": 0,
    "errmsg": "",
    "rtval": [
        true,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (true){
        nextLine =buff.readLine();  
        if (nextLine !=null){
           System.out.println(nextLine);      
        }
        else break;

        // I added that line and solved my problem
        System.out.println(nextLine.substring((Integer.valueOf(nextLine.indexOf('[')) + 1),(Integer.valueOf(nextLine.indexOf(']')))));

    }
}
catch(MalformedURLException e) { System.out.println("Check URL :" + e.toString() ); }
```

OUTPUT of Console : {"Result":[18627],"Status":"OK"}
                    18627

Thanks for your interest